# Communication between fragments in a ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a Fragment that has a ViewPager. Each fragment inside of the ViewPager shows some data based on a SearchBar that is in the main fragment. The main Fragment has also a public method called `getKeyword()` (that returns the string of the SearchBar). But I don't know how to get a reference of the main Fragment inside of the ViewPager fragments.

I tried using the `onAttach()` method to get a reference but it returns a reference of the `mainActivity` instead.

I also tried using `getChildFragmentManager()` to get the main Fragment but I don't know what is the id of the main Fragment (The main fragment is actually a fragment from another ViewPager).

Comment: Use events to notify each subscriber here

Comment: Have you tried to call getParentFragment()? What is "main fragment"?

Comment: @Buckstabue  It worked!

Answer (score 2):

The better way to communicate between fragment is using a Callback interface,

1. you create the interface on the Fragment that contains the search bar text
2. then you implement that interface on the Activity
3. on the onAttach method of the fragment that has the search text and also created the interface you create an instance of the interface Callback and fill it casting the Activity to the instance of your Callback

`public class MainFragment extends Fragment {`

```
   //all your other stuff
   private MyFragment.Callback myCallback;

   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
       super.onAttach(activity);
       if( activity instanceOf MyFragment.Callback ) {
           myCallback = (MyFragment.Callback) activity;
       } else {
           /*here you manage the case when the activity does not have the interface callback implemented*/
           //Generally with this
           throws new ClassCastException(
               activity.class.getSimpleName() +
                " should implement " +
                 MyFragment.class.getSimpleName()
                 );
        }
    }

    private void thisMethodIsUsedWhenTheSearchIsExecuted(String searchText) {
        //here you get the string of the search however you need
        myCallback.callWhenSearch(searchText);
    }

    public interface Callback {
        void callWhenSearch(String searchText);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the activity that manages the fragments

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragment.Callback {
// anything you need for the main activity
    public void callWhenSearch(String searchText) {
    //searchText will contain the text of the search executed on MyFragment
    //and here you can execute a method that calls the fragment where you need to see the result of your search for example

        instanceOfSecondFragment.visualizeResultsOf(searchText)

    }
}
```

You can have some official documentation here:

[Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

If you need more help please let me know.

Comment: Nice Explorations

Comment: I tried that solution, but the problem is when I try to cast the `Activity` I'm getting my MainActivity instead of the Fragment.